# NodeJS y Express - Un test me esta fallando por problemas de auth y no encuentro el motivo

Tags: nodejs, api, express, test, mocha

me he embarcado en la aventura de aprender node y ya me han salido los primeros problemas. Estoy haciendo test con Mocha sobre la api que estoy realizando en node, y tengo problemas con la autenticación, que para ello estoy usando passport y jwt. El problema viene cuando hago un test para comprobar un 200 pasándole un token a pincho por el body, de prueba, y me devuelve 401

Aquí pongo el archivo donde hago los test de auth

```
const passport = require('passport');
//chai es una libreria externa que permite validar la informacion de una variable mediante funciones
const chai = require('chai');

//plugin de chai, que le permite levantar servers y hacer calls http sobre estos servers
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

//Para poder hacer los test de endpoint, hay que llamar a donde esta ubicado el backend, que es el archivo app.js
//.app es para llamar al objeto que es el servidor.
const app = require('../app').app;

//para decirle a chai que se quiere usar el plugin http se le indica con la funcionalidad use
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Suite de pruebas Auth', () => {

    it('devuelve 401 cuando el usuario no esta autorizado', (done) => {

        //aqui se le dice a chai que use el servidor que esta definido en el archivo
        chai.request(app)

            //Aqui se esta diciendo que haga la llamada http al servidor usando el protocolo indicado
            .get('/team')

            //recoje una funcion que le permite interactuar con el resultado de la llamada
            .end((err, res) => {

                //se comprueba que la respuesta se igual que el codigo de status http 
                chai.assert.equal(res.status, 401);

                //se finaliza el test
                done();
            });
    });

    it('devuelve 200 cuando el token jwt es valido', (done) => {

        //aqui se le dice a chai que use el servidor que esta definido en el archivo
        chai.request(app)

            //Aqui se esta diciendo que haga la llamada http al servidor usando el protocolo indicado
            .post('/login')

            //recoje una funcion que le permite interactuar con el resultado de la llamada
            .end((err, res) => {

                //una vez en el post que recoje el token, se vuelve a lanzar otra vez chai para hacer otra
                //peticion a un get y comprobar el token
                chai.request(app)

                    .get('/team')

                    //se le envia un header para realizar la comprobacion JWT
                    .set('Authorization', `jwt ${res.body.token}`)

                    .end((err, res) => {

                        //si el token es valido se  recibe un 200
                        chai.assert.equal(res.status, 200);

                        //se finaliza el test
                        done();
                    });
            });
    });
});
```

Aqui el app.js

```
//se importa la libreria de express con un require
const express = require('express');

//se importa la libreria de passport con un require
const passport = require('passport');

//se define la variable que va a tener las capacidades de usar las funcionalidades de express
const app = express();

//se define el puerto de conexion que va usar express
const port = 3000;

//se llama a la funcion que comprueba las autenticaciones
require('./auth')(passport);

//se llama al objeto listen de la const app para empezar escuchar conexiones, sino se ejecutaria
//y acabaria cerrandose, despues se abren llaves a metodo de funcion callback para que realice acciones
//iniciar el server.
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('El servidor ha empezado en el puerto ' + port);
})

//esta funcion es una peticion get que se puede lanzar desde la constante que almacena 
//las funcionalidades de express. "req" => request y "res" => response
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    //con la funcionalidad ".send" se le devuelve al cliente una respuesta a la peticion
    res.status(200).send('hola mundo');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(
        { token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.XbPfbIHMI6arZ3Y922BhjWgQzWXcXNrz0ogtVhfEd2o' }
    )
});


app.get('/team',
    //al usar esta ruta se verificara quien la use posea un JWT, es un middleware
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {

        res.status(200).send('hola mundo');

    });

app.post('/team/pokemons', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('hola mundo');
});

app.delete('/team/pokemons/:pokeid', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('hola mundo');
});

app.put('/team', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('hola mundo');
});


module.exports.app = app;
```

y por ultimo el archo auth en el que tengo todo el tema passport y JWT

```
//libreria importada para usar passport. Strategy se usa para crear una estrategia de autenticacion (eso creo)
const jwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;

const extractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

//Se exporta esta funcion a la que se le pasa passport por parametro
module.exports = passport => {

    //esto crearia un objeto JSON que seria la estrategia a utilizar
    const opts = {
        //esta linea especifica de donde se sacara el jwt en el momento de hacer la peticion
        jwtFromRequest: extractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("JWT"),
        secretOrKey: 'secretPassword'
    }
    //aqui se indica a passport que use la estrategia creada anteriormente, y dentro se le mete una funcion
    //de resultado, para hacer comprobaciones
    passport.use(new jwtStrategy(opts,(decoded, done) =>{
        console.log('decoded jwt', decoded);
        return done(null, false);
    }));
}
```

al terminar el test me da error en la línea 59 del archivos de los test, concretamente en `chai.assert.equal(res.status, 200);` pero no entiendo donde está el error. Adjunto una foto del resultado de los test.
[image: resultados test mocha]